# How to deduct one day from the date in xpath?

Tags: datetime, xpath, soapui, saxon

I write automated tests using SOAPUI free version. 
I have such format of date which I take from sql database:

```
2015-11-30 13:38:58.387
```

I need to convert it to a ormat like:

```
2015-11-30T13:38:58.387 or 2015-11-30
```

And deduct one day from it, so that to get the date minus one day.

I tried to use `previous-day()`function and `substring-before()` (using XPath):

```
previous-day(substring-before((//*:Results/*:ResultSet/*:Row/*:VALIDFROM/text()), ' '))
```

But it always gives an error like:

```
net.sf.saxon.trans.XPathException:XPath syntax error at char 87 {../*:Row/*:VALIDFROM/text()..}: Unknown system function previous-day()
```

Why doen't these functions work?

Thank you

Comment: Your use of XPath suggests that you don't handle XML namespaces properly. You should fix that as well, it's not hard to do.

Comment: The reason the previous-day() function doesn't work is that it doesn't exist. What made you think that it did?

Comment: I took it from this source http://www.xqueryfunctions.com/xq/functx_previous-day.html

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
xs:dateTime(translate(//x, ' ', 'T')) - xs:dayTimeDuration('P1D')
```

where `//x` stands in for your node selection.

Hat tip to Michael Kay who pointed this out in the comments.

Comment: alternatively `xs:dateTime(translate(//x, ' ', 'T')) - xs:dayTimeDuration('P1D')`

Comment: Almost, that doesn't account for the dot that T-SQL datetimes have.

Comment: Fractional seconds are quite legal in an xs:dateTime value.

Comment: @MichaelKay Thank you, you are of course right. I took the liberty of updating my answer with your much simpler suggestion.

Comment: thanks for your suggestions. I use this variant: 

`xs:date(substring-before(//*:Results/*:ResultSet/*:Row/*:VALIDFROM, ' ')) - xs:dayTimeDuration('P1D')`

which gives me: 

`Sat Oct 03 02:00:00 CEST 2015`

but I need formats like:

`2015-11-30T13:38:58.387` or `2015-11-30`

Do you know what function can be used here?

Comment: I've no idea what code is converting your date to an IETF representation, but it's not the XPath code you have shown us. If you want to control the formatting, use format-dateTime().